# Usage of "aufführen" and "auftreten"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I have googled these verbs and nothing came up. I would like to know if *aufführen* and *auftreten* mean to perform?

> 1. Die Beatles haben 1966 im Araneta Colliseum in Manila ***aufgeführt.***
> 2. Die Skorpions sind im Hotel 'HP Pavillion' in San Jose ***aufgetreten.***

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auffuehren

Comment: @CarstenSchultz for a beginner a German-German dictionary might not  be very helpful. I remember that I hated that in school in English class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add another meaning of aufführen:

Aufführen can be used synonymously to `auflisten` which means <s>obviously</s> to list something:

> Auf der Rückseite sind die Zutaten aufgeführt.

Furthermore:

Aufführen is used in combination with a "thing" and it conveys the general meaning of presenting something. But it can also be used in a sense of throwing a fit. To use it in this way there exists a reflexive form:

> Er führt sich heute wieder auf wie der letzte Dreck!

Auftreten on the other hand can also describe the simple act of stepping on stage:

> Die Beatles traten auf und die Menge spielte verrück

As well as something similar to `happen`:

> Es trat ein Zwischenfall auf.

Answer (score 2):

yes, actually it means the same. There is just a small difference :

```
aufführen == ein Stück(a play) aufführen
auftreten == an einem Ort auftreten oder an einem Ort aufführen
```

**and yes, it means perform :)

Comment: *Jemand tritt auf und führt dabei etwas auf*. -  Das bedeutet dann auch, dass der erste Satz in der Frage falsch ist, denn dort fehlt noch, **was** sie aufgeführt haben. ;)

Comment: Da muss ich dir aber widersprechen , man kann meiner Meinung nach auch  ohne genauere angaben zu z.B dem Stück aufführen benutzen !

Comment: @HansPeter er führt sich heute wieder mal auf, nicht wahr?

Comment: Sein Auftritt bei der morgigen Aufführung wird im Fernsehen übertragen.

Comment: Ja,.. Immer der Em1 ;)

Comment: no it's not the same

Comment: Like i said. Small difference

Answer (score 2):

All the other meanings of the words aside, *aufführen* is what you do to the piece.

> Ich führe etwas auf.
>
> I perform something.

*Auftreten* is what the performers do.

> Ich trete auf.
>
> I perform.

You can say

> Ich führe auf

but everyone will ask what you are performing because *aufführen* is about the piece
You cannot say

> Ich trete Hamlet auf.

That is just wrong as *auftreten* works like *gehen* and can take no object.
Thus, ultimately the answer is that they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both @Hans Peter's and @Emanuel's answers are better than the accepted one.

The accepted answer doesn't shed any light on the actual question. :)

The big difference between "auftreten" and "aufführen" is indeed the fact that "auftreten" is intransitive, whereas "aufführen" is transitive, and requires a direct object.

On that note: the sample sentence with "aufführen" is incomplete, it's lacking the object. ;D